# Mark as read in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I'd like to know how I can mark all messages with a certain tag as read, all at once.

I have around 2000 unread messages with a certain tag, and I don't want to go through endless pages of "select all" -> "mark as read"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Perform a search to find all the messages you want to select. (You can use `is:unread` too)
2. Click **select all**
3. You will see that above the first item in the list there is a banner that says something like: `All 50 conversations on this page are selected. Select all # conversations in "..."`; click that link.

You can also do this with a filter, by creating the filter, choosing to mark the messages as read, and then choosing to apply the filter to the matching conversations. Then simply delete the filter.